# Can I get the more than the last x articles from an RSS feed?

Tags: xml, rss

Going to http://feedproxy.google.com/ILoveTypography in my browser or curl, gets the last 15 articles, the number is set by the blog engine I'm guessing. Adding the feed to Google Reader however, I can scroll down to the bottom and it'l AJAX load the next 15 or 20 items in the list, and you can keep scrolling down and it'l forever load up more articles. It's not just feedproxy.google.com - I tried with the MSDN blog as well, as a newly subscribed feed.

Is Google keeping the full feed? Do I have to manually scroll through the full blog history in Google Reader, save the AJAX generated HTML then parse it to get the info I want?

Comment: Someone edit that link - it's got an extra "http://" in there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get it from Google's archives using:

http://www.google.com/reader/atom/feed/http://feeds.feedburner.com/ILoveTypography?n=50

Try changing the value of 'n' to see how many items can be retrieved.

Answer (score 0):

Google Reader is keeping the all item since the first time it crawled it. Google Feedproxy/Feedburner it's only a copy of the original feed (say: ilovetypography.com/feed)

You can either pass a value to the original feed to get more items, again, say: ilovetypography.com/feed**?page=2** but that depends totally on the feed itself.

ps. I don't know if there is a way to get the full feed from Google Reader archive

Answer (score 0):

Here is someone who has had some success getting the data out of Google Reader's own api: http://www.niallkennedy.com/blog/2005/12/google-reader-api.html